# How to display only time part from date time combination in java

Tags: java, time

I am new to Java. I am retrieving my first column from database in a String Array which represents data as:

```
2014-09-01 10:00:00.000
```

Now I want to display only time as:

```
10:00:00
```

How to do it?
My code to retrieve my Column is:

```js
public String[] getChartTime() throws SQLException {
  List < String > timeStr = new ArrayList < String > ();
  String atime[] = null;
  getConnection();
  try {
    con = getConnection();


    String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("date is " + df.format(currentDate));
    clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql);
    clstmt.setString(1, "vs3_bag");
    clstmt.setString(2, "2014-09-01 10:00:00");
    clstmt.setString(3, "2014-09-01 11:00:00");
    clstmt.execute();
    rs = clstmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
      // Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
      timeStr.add(rs.getString(1));

    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean in getDbTable(String code):" + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection();
  }
  // I would return the list here, but let's convert it to an array
  atime = timeStr.toArray(new String[timeStr.size()]);
  for (String s: atime) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }

  return atime;


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. Your Question's topics have been addressed in hundreds of questions and answers. Tips: (1) when serializing a date-time value to a string, use the standard ISO 8601 format. (2) For a database, use a date-time data type rather than strings. Probably TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Databases such as Postgres support an array of such values.

Answer (score 8):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

If you have the date as a String, you can parse it to a java.util.Date in a step before:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YOUR_DATE_PATTERN");
Date date = sdf.parse(string);
```

Use patterns according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood the question correctly `2014-09-01 10:00:00.000` is in a string and `10:00:00` has to be extracted from that. Given below is my solution.

- First split the string with space as the delimiter.
- Then from that take the second part of the string.
- After that split the string again using `.` as the delimiter and take the first sting from that.

The above things are done using the line.

```
str.split("\\s")[1].split("\\.")[0];
```

### COMPLETE CODE

```
String str = new String("2014-09-01 10:00:00.000");
String time = str.split("\\s")[1].split("\\.")[0];
System.out.print(time);
```

### OUTPUT

```
10:00:00
```

> For more details check the links given below:
>
> - [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).
> - [Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)

Comment: I don't have to pass date and time as it is but have to pass a string array which holds my column values.how to do that.I have edited my question.How can i pass atime which is string array with values of my column.Moreover what is str1 in your line of code.

Comment: how to split an array of string type which contains combination of date and time into time part only.Is there any way to do so.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA In what form is your array can you give an example

Comment: my array atime is of string type which holds around 3600 values of the form 2014-09-01 10:00:00.000

Answer (score 2):

Refer [official Java docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;


    public class MyDate {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
            Date date = new Date();
            String time=dateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(time);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it,just use substring() as

```
 while(rs.next()) {
            // Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
            timeStr.add(rs.getString(1).substring(11,16));

        }
```